# SubArray won't display values

Tags: android, arrays, loops, kotlin

I created an `int` subArray from another `int` array, and when I use the following code to set those values as text values in a seekbar:

```
 Timber.d("TICK TEXT VALUES: -> ${arrayOf(subArray.contentToString())}")
 mySeekBar.customTickTexts(arrayOf(subArray.contentToString()))
```

`customTickTexts` accepts a string array as an argument.

I get the following result:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@b23e68c
```

But when I print the sub-array it does print the `subArray`

```
 Timber.d("SUB-ARRAY-> ${subArray.contentToString()}")

 //Output
 SUB-ARRAY-> [10, 20, 50, 80, 90, 100, 110]
```

This is the `customTickTexts` function (Note that this function is from [this library](https://github.com/warkiz/IndicatorSeekBar)

```
public void customTickTexts(@NonNull String[] tickTextsArr) {
        this.mTickTextsCustomArray = tickTextsArr;
        if (mTickTextsArr != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTickTextsArr.length; i++) {
                String tickText;
                if (i < tickTextsArr.length) {
                    tickText = String.valueOf(tickTextsArr[i]);
                } else {
                    tickText = "";
                }
                int index = i;
                if (mR2L) {
                    index = mTicksCount - 1 - i;
                }
                mTickTextsArr[index] = tickText;
                if (mTextPaint != null && mRect != null) {
                    mTextPaint.getTextBounds(tickText, 0, tickText.length(), mRect);
                    mTickTextsWidth[index] = mRect.width();
                }
            }
            invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Any help or advice as to why it won't print the actual values and I get this result:  `[Ljava.lang.String;@b23e68c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `map` function to convert array of **int** into array of **strings**:

```
mySeekBar.customTickTexts(subArray.map { it.toString() })
```

Comment: I tried that but then it says: `Required Array<(out)>String! found String! wrap element with arrayOf() call` But when I CTRL+ CLICK the `customTickTexts` function it shows the declration as `public void customTickTexts(@NonNull String[] tickTextsArr)`

Note that the customTickTexts is from [this](https://github.com/warkiz/IndicatorSeekBar) library

Comment: Updated, please check

Comment: unfortunately that did not work either, still gave me this `[Ljava.lang.String;@76c5e6b` as a result

Comment: how do you print those results? It is also would be great to see `customTickTexts` function

Comment: I have edited my question with the `customTickTexts` fuction. Also I print those results with `Timber` just to test. I just want to set my seekbar with intervals from the array and was trying this method out by setting the texts at the intervals.

Comment: when you call `mySeekBar.customTickTexts` as i described, does it show intervals? Or it has some errors?

Comment: It does show the intervals but the value of the seekbar progress doesn't change to the corresponding text on the seekbar.

Comment: maybe you should call `showIndicatorType(...)` method on `IndicatorSeekBar` object

Comment: Seems need to dig into the library.

Comment: I got it nevermind, had to use `seekBar.setIndicatorTextFormat("${TICK_TEXT}")` Thank you so much for your time and help, much appreciated.